# Trying to call assembly procedure from another assembly file and I get undefined symbol error

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to call multiple procedures that are in another location and I am not sure why my declared constant variables in my main.asm are not being identified when called in my algorithm.asm file.
Here is a snippet of the algorithm.asm code:

```
 INCLUDE C:/Irvine/Irvine32.inc
 .data 
 .code 
 getUserData PROC
     push ebp
     mov ebp, esp
     jmp userPrompt

 error:
     mov edx, [ebp + 8]  ;// Out of range prompt 
     call WriteString
     call CrLf
 userPrompt:
     mov eax, [ebp + 12]
     mov eax, 0
     mov edx, [ebp + 16] ;// Displays instructions for user
     call WriteString
     call ReadInt        ;// Gets user input

     cmp eax, MIN
     JL error
     cmp eax, MAX
     JG error

     mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
     mov[ebx], eax

     pop ebp
     ret 12

 getUserData ENDP
 END
```

And for my main.asm code:

```
 INCLUDE C:/Irvine/Irvine32.inc
 INCLUDE algorithm.inc 

 .data  
 MIN = 16
 MAX = 256
```

Why is this not allowing my constants in main.asm to be read in algorithm.asm?
I've tried copying and pasting my constants into algorithm.asm's .data and while that does work, I want to know how to reference without doing this method, if possible.

Comment: How exactly are you "declaring" `MIN` and `MAX` in the other file?

Comment: just under the .data as: MAX = 256, then under that MIN = 16 in the Main.asm file

Comment: If they are constants, they aren't going to be in data section.  The assembler will use them to produce the output, but there won't be any MIN/MAX defined in that object file.  Perhaps you could create a constants.inc, then have both files include it?